# Nginx with subdirectory

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to get the following configuration to work inside a subdirectory /dev but I'm quite new to Nginx and can't seem to get it to work properly.

If you look at the below configuration, you'll see subdirectories such as ***content***, ***site***, etc. All of those directories are inside another subdirectory ***/dev***. For example: ***root/dev/content***, ***root/dev/site***, etc.

Can anyone lend a hand so that I can access the /dev site properly?

```
# block content
location ~ ^/content/(.*).(txt|md|mdown)$ {
    rewrite ^/content/(.*).(txt|md|mdown)$ /error redirect;
}

# block all files in the site folder from being accessed directly
location ~ ^/site/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/site/(.*)$ /error redirect;
}

# block all files in the kirby folder
location ~ ^/kirby/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/kirby/(.*)$ /error redirect;
}

# site links
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}

# panel links
location /panel {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /panel/index.php?$uri&$args;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: I really don't get it when ppl give -1 and not leave a comment why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding /dev to most of the config solves it.

```
# block content
location ~ ^/dev/content/(.*).(txt|md|mdown)$ {
    rewrite ^/dev/content/(.*).(txt|md|mdown)$ /error redirect;
}

# block all files in the site folder from being accessed directly
location ~ ^/dev/site/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/dev/site/(.*)$ /error redirect;
}

# block all files in the kirby folder
location ~ ^/dev/kirby/(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/dev/kirby/(.*)$ /error redirect;
}

# site links
location /dev {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /dev/index.php?$uri&$args;
}

# panel links
location /dev/panel {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /dev/panel/index.php?$uri&$args;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```